# How to move data from on SQL server to another using BCP

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, bcp

I wanted to move data from SQL server on machine A to SQL server on machine B using BCP. The BCP command will be running on machine C. I installed SQL server Express on C so that I can run BCP command.

I have been connecting to SQL Server on A using SQL Server Management Studio via Windows authentication without providing a password.[image]

Server B will be on AWS which has not been set up yet. But it will be configured in a traditional way which requires username password. For now I just wanted to establish connection between SQL server on A and machine C which I run bcp command. How can it be done?

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, source SQL server and the job server where `bcp` is run on are both behind company firewall while the target SQL server is on AWS. Any I have no control over the company SQL server which means I cannot install anything for the migration on the source SQL server A. I can only access it on my machine C.

Comment: You mean in a virtual machine instance, right? At least in azure you can add a firewall rule that can allow you to connect from your machine to your virtual machine instance...aws should have something equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your instances is hosted in AWS I would recommend looking at [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/).

It deals with copying all your data and schema from one SQL instance to another, even outside of AWS.

Comment: what if that source SQL instance is not just outside AWS but also behind company firewall. Would this migration service still work?

Comment: The migration service would require access to the internal SQL instance but yes, it can do on-site instances too.